# How to clear the dropdown list box after refresing whole page. using asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list boxes in the page.

When I Load the page. the dorpdown list boxes values not showing Please Select.. its allways showing the previously selcted value.

why its not defaulting it to Please select is that I am doing something wrong in this aspx page?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because it is finding existing values for those drop down lists in the ModelState and applying those.

Try adding this code to your Index method:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

This is assuming you mean after you click the Save button?

Comment: Yes Richard after clicking in the save button its redirecting back to index page.

Answer (score 1):

That's a function in the browser. It remembers what you entered in the form previously, and fills the form automatically.

Press `Ctrl`+`F5` to reload the page without remembering form data.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behavior of most of the browser. You need to do Ctrl + F5 to reload it fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Load the dropdown on

$(document).ready(function () {

});